# How do I get the value of a descendant element?

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file containing a series of elements like the following:

```
<trkpt lat="42.403128" lon="-71.084654">
    <ele>12.153809</ele>
    <time>2002-03-11T20:49:26Z</time>
    <sym>Waypoint</sym>
</trkpt>
```

I'm using the following code to grab the `lat` and `lon` attributes and add them to a list:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

XElement trkseg = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "trkseg").FirstOrDefault();
XNamespace ns = trkseg.Name.Namespace;

var l_l = trkseg.Elements(ns + "trkpt").Select(x => new
{
    lat = x.Attribute("lat").Value,
    lon = x.Attribute("lon").Value
}).ToList();
```

The above code works as expected. I get a list of strings containing the `lat` and `lon` values. We're good so far.

The problem enters when I try to get the value of the `<time>` element. I've tried several different variations of the following, to no avail:

```
lat = x.Attribute("lat").Value,
lon = x.Attribute("lon").Value,
time = x.Descendants("time").Elements().FirstOrDefault().Value
```

All my attempts resulted in `time` being `null`. How do I get the value of the `<time>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from `ns` being used to access `trkpt` element despite the element has no namespace prefix, then I believe your XML has default namespace somewhere above `trkpt` element level. In this case, `time` element inherits the same namespace as `trkpt`, so you might be simply missing the `XNamespace` :

```cs
time = x.Element(ns+"time").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this'll work for your whole solution, but based on what you provided, I was able to get this to work:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

XElement trkseg = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "trkseg").FirstOrDefault();
XNamespace ns = trkseg.Name.Namespace;

var l_l = trkseg.Elements(ns + "trkpt").Select(x => new
{
    lat = x.Attribute("lat").Value,
    lon = x.Attribute("lon").Value,
    time = x.Element("time").Value
}).ToList();
```

It's easy to over-complicate XML (I say that from personal experience); in this case it looks like you were digging further than you needed when you were already in a level of the xml you needed to be in.

Here's the output I got:

```
{ lat = "42.403128", lon = "-71.084654", time = "2002-03-11T20:49:26Z" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `time = x.Element("time").Value` to my code but `time` is still `null`.